# Microsoft Photos App keeps crashing

Tags: crash, windows-store-app, windows-photo-viewer

Recently, I noticed the Windows 10 default photo app "Photos" crashes.  It doesnt matter if I use it to open an image, or if just try to open it by double clicking the app.  I finally got annoyed enough to look into it.  This appears to be a bug that has been around for at least a year.  Online, there are several videos and web pages relating to this bug, or more likely a similar one.  The "common" bug throws the error `File System Error (-2147219195)`.  However, I get a *slightly* different error of `File System Error (-2147219196)`.  There are several videos and websites that offer several solutions to the former.  However, none of those solutions have worked.  Resetting, clearing the cache, and reinstalling have not worked.

Does anyone know of a solution?

Comment: Did you check what is displayed in events of OS? Did you consider usage of different software?

Comment: "consider usage of other software?"  How does using other software *FIX* the problem?

Comment: In some cases is much easy to find other software compared to resolve the problem :)

Comment: @Keltari - What version of the application are you using?  I currently have `Microsoft Photos 2019.19071.17920.0` installed on my 1909 system

Comment: @Ramhound Well, I did delete it and reinstall it.  So its currently at the latest version of 2019.19081.22010.0

Comment: @Keltari - [This is a known issue with your processor and this specific application.  There isn't a fix for the issue at this time](https://www.neowin.net/news/windows-10-users-report-broken-apps-on-old-computers/#comments).  The likelihood of you have the exact same error, and while you originally asked this question in 2019, I suspect the two reports are connected. I just realized I am repeating what an answer suggested.

Comment: @Ramhound heh.  well, I dont have that computer anymore, so it doesnt really matter now.  I dont remember if it ever got fixed or not...

Answer (score 0):

My parents are seeing this error (file system error 2147219196) when attempting to open photos on their Intel Core2 Duo PC, which is admittedly about 13 years old.

It may be that [a recent update removed support for the CPU](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/microsoft-photos-file-system-error-2147219196/3bf0b7d0-4390-46f2-b948-a1e05d726e73), and the Photos app no longer works on it.

I've downloaded the free open-source version of ImageGlass (["ImageGlass Classic"](https://imageglass.org/release/imageglass-9-0-9-1230-49)) and set that as the default app for opening images.

I saw the same problem with movie files opening in Movies and TV, but I switched those to open in the Media Player app, and that worked.